# Bangladesh Tourist Visa: What does " Group/Order By: FM , ICP , Visa Cell " mean?

Tags: visas, tourist-visas, bangladesh

I am slightly confused here. I am in Part 5: Bangladesh Visa Office Information section of the visa application. It is asking me to choose between three options.

The question is: "Group/Order By:" and my options are: a) FM b) ICP c) Visa Cell

What does this mean?

Comment: Are you completely sure that's not a part of the form that's for the bureaucracy to fill out internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section is titled *"Bangladesh Visa Office Information section"* and is intended to be filled in by the visa office.

You should leave this area blank.

Answer (score 2):

- FM - Foreign Mission
- ICP - International Check Post
- Visa Cell - Visa Cell

On click "Group / Order By" "Select from which Bangladesh Visa Office you want to take Visa" should be changed so you will be able to pick the suitable location.

- Example FM: If you are in India and the nearest Bangladesh mission is in Kolkata, after selecting FM, you should be able to select "KOLKATA"
- Example ICP: If you are in the airport in Dhaka, after selecting ICP, you should be able to select "HAZRAT SHAH JALAL INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT"
- Example Visa Cell: If you are in Dhaka, after selecting Visa Cell, you should be able to select "AGARGAON"

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying from outside Bangladesh, select `FM`. The options `ICP` and `visa cell` are for collecting the visa from locations/offices in Bangladesh itself.